# Is it possible to return an array of dictionaries?

Tags: asp.net-core

I wrote a function that will return a single sql record as a dictionary. Is it possible to return an array of dictionaries so I can return multiple records in this way?

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> SQLMultiRecordToDictionary(string TableName, string SearchField, string SearchValue)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> QueryResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // is TableName sane
        if (!IsTextSane(TableName)) { return QueryResult; }
        //
        await using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFullPathName))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqliteCommand sqlcmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + SearchField + "=@SearchValue";
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchValue", SearchValue);

            SqliteDataReader sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            // generate dictionary keys with blank values
            // this prevents key not existing issues when no record is returned
            // i prefer no/blank values in the keys when no record returned for this project
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlreader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                QueryResult.Add(sqlreader.GetName(i), ""); // blank value
            }
            // add the values to the keys
            while (sqlreader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= sqlreader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    QueryResult[sqlreader.GetName(i)] = sqlreader.GetString(i);
                }
            }
            return QueryResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use List<<Dictionary<string, string>> instead and then add your records to this list

Comment: Oh I like that idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working end result thanks to Tisa:

```
public static async Task<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> SQLMultiRecordToDictionaryList(string TableName, string SearchField, string SearchValue)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> QueryResult = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        Dictionary<string, string> SQLRecord = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //
        // is TableName sane, if not return nothing
        if (!IsTextSane(TableName)) { return QueryResult; }
        //
        await using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFullPathName))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqliteCommand sqlcmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + SearchField + "=@SearchValue";
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchValue", SearchValue);

            SqliteDataReader sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

            // generate dictionary keys with blank values if no rows
            // this prevents key not existing issues when no record is returned
            // i prefer no/blank values in the keys when no record returned for this project
            if (!sqlreader.HasRows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sqlreader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    SQLRecord.Add(sqlreader.GetName(i), ""); // blank value
                }
                QueryResult.Add(SQLRecord);
            }
            //
            // add the values to the keys if there are rows (this doesn't run if no rows returned)
            while (sqlreader.Read())
            {
                SQLRecord = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= sqlreader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    SQLRecord.Add(sqlreader.GetName(i), sqlreader.GetString(i));
                }
                QueryResult.Add(SQLRecord);
            }
            return QueryResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you have solved it, you can accept your answer as the best answer,then it will help more people